# javascript touchstart event to trigger css transform animation

Tags: jquery, ios, css, css-animations

I'm trying out the css3 'card-flip' technique, as far as I tested it works great, except in iOS.
The first time you 'swipe' the animation will be triggered. The second time it does nothing. You can watch the example [here](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip).

Here's what I tried:
1. Put the javascript in a separate file

```
jQuery('.flip-container').on('touchstart', function(){
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

2. Added z-index property about everywhere
3. Changed the 'animation' to something simple like adding a border to the container
4. Changed ontouchstart to ontouchmove

The script works fine, the class 'hover' is always toggled. It seems like iOS just doesn't want to 'render' the changes more than once...

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have forgotten to add `-webkit` prefix to CSS properties.

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Also, I have removed `:hover` from the below line, so I guess it was conflicting with `touchstart`.

```
/* .flip-container:hover .flipper, */ .flip-container.hover .flipper {
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

After doing the changes, I tested this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xLn81woa/5/) in iPhone Safari and it worked as it should.

Comment: Didn't forget the prefixes but you are right, :hover was the bad guy here.
Does this mean that there is no way to have this work on hover and on swipe (since hover doedn't exist on touch device)

Comment: @Gregory Well, actually, `:hover` does exist, check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xLn81woa/6/) on your iDevice. The issue with `:hover` is you have to touch _outside_ the element in order to remove `:hover` propert/effect.